# How to build one query of two group in two table? I want to get result for same that original results

Tags: php, mysql, sql

How to build one query of two group in two table?

**TABLE A**

```
ID  NAME
1   BBB
2   CCC
3   DDD
4   EEE
```

**TABLE B**

```
ID  (TABLE A).ID   VISIT   CPC  
1      2            1      0.26
2      2            1      0.26
3      2            1      0.28
4      2            1      0.28
5      2            1      0.30
6      1            1      0.75
7      1            1      0.75
8      1            1      0.75
9      1            1      0.20
10     1            1      0.20
11     4            1      0.80
12     4            1      0.80
13     4            1      0.40
14     4            1      0.40
15     4            1      0.40
16     3            1      1.15
17     3            1      1.15
18     3            1      1.25
19     3            1      1.25
20     3            1      1.35

**Original Results**



NAME  TOTAL VISIT   TOTAL COST ( SUM(VISIT) * CPC )

BBB    5            1.38
CCC    5            2.65
DDD    5            2.8
EEE    5            6.15
```

**First getting results for group by TABLE A.ID and then GROUP BY CPC in TABLE B.**
 Make only one query

Just reply for this matters

Comment: If you don't know how to write a JOIN, you need to read some SQL tutorials.

Comment: StackOverflow expects you to [try to solve your own problem first](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/261592), and we also [don't answer homework questions](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6166). Please update your question to show what you have already tried in a [minimal, complete, and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). For further information, please see [how to ask good questions](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), and take the [tour of the site](http://stackoverflow.com/tour) :)

Comment: Do you really mean `GROUP BY CPC`? Shouldn't it be `GROUP BY TableAID`?

Comment: Yes first group by Table A.ID then after group by CPC

Comment: If you group by CPC, you'll have more than one row in the result for each name, since you'll have a row for each CPC.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your Result table's final column formula is not right actually this has the some of `CPC`.If I a correct then the following query may help your better.

```
select NAME from TABLE_A 
inner join (select TABLE_A_ID,sum(VISIT) `TOTAL VISIT`, sum(CPC) `TOTAL COST` from TABLE_B group by TABLE_A_ID) t1 on t1.TABLE_A_ID = TABLE_A.ID
```

# Update as per your comment.use the conditional statement in subquery:

```
select NAME,`TOTAL VISIT`,`TOTAL COUNT`,`TOTAL COST` from TABLE_A inner join (select TABLE_A_ID,sum(VISIT) `TOTAL VISIT`,count(VISIT) `TOTAL COUNT`, sum(CPC) `TOTAL COST` from TABLE_B where TABLE_B.VISIT = 1 group by TABLE_A_ID,CPC) t1 on t1.TABLE_A_ID = TABLE_A.ID
```

Comment: Getting correct results..Thanks

Comment: But one small issue .

Comment: inner join must be sum of visit group of cpc for parent table id

Comment: try once the updated solution.

Comment: that your second query actually same result ,  i want group by cpc

Comment: after that group count of total visit then sum of total visit

Comment: check it now...

Comment: Thanks..this is now correct.

Answer (score 1):

**TRY THIS**: `(TABLE A).ID` is changed to id1 so please change it accordingly before trying it.

```
SELECT MAX(t.name) name, sum(t1.visit) total_visit, sum(cpc) AS total_cost
FROM tablea t
INNER JOIN tableb t1 on t.id = t1.id1
GROUP BY t.id
```

Answer (score 0):

As @addy mentioned earlier, the formula given for `total cpc` count is not correct. You have different `cpc` values for same `name`.
Using `JOIN` there is no need to have any sub-query. You may try this -

```
SELECT name, SUM(visit) as total_visit, SUM(cpc) as total_cpc 
FROM B 
JOIN A
ON B.a_id = A.id
GROUP BY name;
```

Here is the [SQL Fiddle link](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/519c9/3/0)